# In Potterverse, what would be as protective as, or stronger than, dragon's hide?

Tags: harry-potter

Dragon's hide seems to be the gold standard when it comes to protective gear at Hogwarts, and basically for the wizarding world as a whole. Harry's school supplies requirements lists the following (among a lot of other items that I will leave out for the sake of brevity):

> **Uniform**
>   *First-year students will require:*
>   1. *Three sets of plain work robes (black*)
>   2. *One plain pointed hat (black) for day wear*
>   3. ***One pair of protective gloves (dragon hide or similar)***
>   4. *One winter cloak (black, silver fastenings)*
>   *Please note that all pupils’ clothes should carry name tags.*

There they are, listed on Harry's letter: Dragon hide gloves or similar. Yet, *are* there similar protective gear? Are there magical creatures whose hides are stronger than dragon's hide? Or are there hides that are perhaps not as good as dragon's hide, but will protect a student in a pinch? Are any examples of students using lesser or stronger protective gear than dragon's hide represented in canon? Any examples you can cite would be great, both of magical creatures with particularly tough hides and of non-dragon hide protective gear (and how well it worked).

<sub>If this question is too scattered, please leave a comment and I'll try and tighten it up. I'm hoping it makes sense, though.</sub>

Comment: Well, you can't use penguin hide, that's for damn sure; https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2aQiLzsK5xU

Comment: I imagine an ancient plot-related pair of artifact magical gloves inherited from the Peverell brothers could measure up, if there's a legend claiming that Death himself gave the gloves he used to hold his sword with.  The problem is, the secret of their creation is lost by now, so we can't tell what creature's hide they're made from.

Comment: Synthetic fibers. Graphene. Nanotubes. Oups, we aren't in HP:MOR are we?

Comment: I felt that my answer to this one was pretty comprehensive, covering the books and pottermore. Is there anything else you'd like to see before considering an acceptance?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In-canon, there's several possible alternatives:

### [Erumpet](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Erumpent)

The hide of the Erumpet is said to be extremely resilient and to resist charms and curses. There's no specific mention of safety clothing made from its skin but it's reasonable to assume this would provide you a reasonable level of protection.

### [Graphorn](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Graphorn)

According to Fantastic Beasts, Graphorn hide is...

> "***...even tougher than a Dragon's*** and repels most spells".

The description seems akin to that of a rhinocerous so it's again quite likely that you could make a set of gloves out of its skin.

### [Tebo](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Tebo)

Fantastic Beasts describes the hide of the Tebo as being especially sought-after and...

> *...highly prized by wizards for protective shields **and clothing***

Comment: giants skin would also probably do the job, however i assume it would illegal to use giant skin gloves in most countries.
and dont forget the skrewts !

Comment: @Himarm - I disregarded skrewts since it's their armour that repels spells and it's not immediately apparent that it's the skin of a giant that affords it protection. Ron attributes it to hagrid's blood (although he could easily be referring to his heritage, not his literal blood).